# Как объединить три select`а (день/месяц/год) в один?

Tags: php, html

У меня есть три select'a. В первом: день. Во втором: месяц. В третьем: год. Я бы хотел, чтобы эти select'ы, заносились в БД одним целым числом (датой). Но как ни пробовал - не получается. Эта штука нужна для регистрации (дата рождения пользователя).

Как эти три select'a объединить в один, чтобы занесло в БД? Или просто забить и убрать эти select'ы?

Comment: а почему бы не использовать любой *datepicker* компонент?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day']
```

Самый простой вариант. Главное значения селектов храни в правильном формате, с текущим нулем впереди.

Comment: Единственное только, что потом будет проблемно сравнивать, если записывать просто с виде строки. Возможно есть какой-то метод (не помню уже), который строку приводит к формату даты. А потом уже эту дату следует записать в поле типа date.

Comment: Не будет никаких проблем,дата будет храниться в бд как следует, в правильном Mysql формате даты.